# Form isn't reading table records

Tags: ms-access

I am really new at building databases. I created a table that reads from other tables. However, I needed to add another table and I placed the input field into the form.

My problem is that the form isn't reading any of the records already on the tables. How did this change and how do I fix it?

Now every time I enter a new record this message comes up.

> The Microsoft database engine can not find a record in the table "  " with key matching fields "  "

Comment: To clarify: do the errors actually provide spaces as the name of the table and the matching fields, or are you just blanking it out yourself to avoid revealing too much about your architecture?

Comment: I just blanked them out myself

Comment: If you want to hide specific aspect of your database that's fine, but at the least create aliases that you can post to make it easier to reference.  Please share specific details necessary to answer the question.  You ask "how did this change?", but saying "placed the input field into the form" does not accurately describe what you changed. Besides adding a new table, did you edit the form's Record Source query?  Did you add indexes and/or relationships?  You likely need to describe the table structure, fields and relationships. It's likely that you're leaving a required, related value null.

Comment: I created a table that is to collect serial numbers for products.  this serial number is inputted by the user and has a relationship to an employee table.  there was nothing changed other than the field that was placed on the form.  when I bring up the form with the new field it doesn't read any records on any tables. I haven't changed anything else. Thanks

Comment: Overall the what you explain still does not make a lot of sense.  You said "I need to add another table", but what does that mean?  So did you add another table or not?  Does this mean you created a completely new table?  Or does it only mean you added another table to the query?  Or does it mean you only added another field from a table already in the query?

Comment: But like I said before, you should **edit the question** and add some details.  Explain your table structure, indexes, relationships and the Form's Record Source query.  Change the names if you have to and perhaps don't show all fields, but at least explain to us how your tables are related and what the form should be displaying.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error. Either you screwed up the 1:M relationship or you are trying to enter data into multiple tables incorrectly

1. From [Microsoft's Developer Network MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210280(v=office.12).aspx) :In a one-to-many relationship, you entered data on the "many" side for which there is no matching record on the "one" side. For example, this error occurs if you join a Customers table and Orders table on a CustomerID field, and then add an order using a CustomerID that does not exist in the Customers table.
2. [From Microsoft Answers:](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/the-microsoft-access-database-engine-cannot-find-a/efb4ffee-4b7b-427a-bdf2-6667bef0d934?auth=1) It sounds like you are trying to enter data into multiple tables using one main form. That's not going to work. You NEED to be using subforms. Create your main form bound to the Members table and then subforms to each of the child tables. Use the Form wizard to create your forms.

My guess from your comments is #2. You added a new table but didn't recreate the form using subforms.